# Function to find variance returns 0

Tags: c, function, variance

I'm working on a program for school that involves finding certain statistics of an array, and one of the things I have to find is the variance, I have a function made for it but for some reason it keeps returning 0

```
double variance(double * array, unsigned int size, double value)
{
    double variance = 0; //Variable used to store the variance
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (value > array[i]) //If statement checks to see if you need to subtract the value from the array or the other way around
        {
            variance += pow((value - array[i]), 2);
        }
        else
        {
            variance += pow((array[i] - value), 2);
        }
    }
    variance /= size; 
    return variance;
}
```

I've tried going through it with the debugger but I came out with nothing

how I called it:

```
double varaince = variance(array, size, mean);
printf("\nVariance: %.3lf", variance);
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mntGv.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, I find it hard to believe that you got absolutely nothing from the debugger. If that is the case then perhaps you should be asking help on how to use a debugger.

Comment: Off topic: the `if` statement is not needed, since squaring the difference will always result in a positive number (even if the difference is negative). On topic: there's nothing that prevents that code from computing a variance, so the problem must be in the code that's not shown. In other words, I agree with @kaylum that you need to post an MCVE.

Comment: different variable names: varaince vs. variance - printf doesn't output the variable, but the adress of the function variance

Comment: I updated the post with how I call it in my main as well as a sample output

Answer (score 2):

As [@ammoQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639572/function-to-find-variance-returns-0#comment58961231_35639572) commented

```
double varaince = variance(array, size, mean);

//                         function name used here.
// printf("\nVariance: %.3lf", variance);

//                       Use variable name
printf("\nVariance: %.3lf", varaince);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    variance/=size;
```

Should be

```
    variance/=(double)size;
```

size on its own is stored as a binary integer.

Comment: Since `variance` is of type `double`, `size` will be promoted to `double` implicitly for the purpose of the division.